# jQuery: adding class to link if its clicked

Tags: jquery, css

I call jquery function onclick  at links. For example:

```
<a class="active" href="#" onClick="Animate2id('#box1');" >Content 1</a>
<a href="#" onClick="Animate2id('#box2');" >Content 2</a>
<a href="#" onClick="Animate2id('#box3');" >Content 3</a>
```

As you can see, first link has by default class 'active'. I want to remove the class from first link and add to the link which is clicked.
For that purpose, I'm trying to add following line inside the Animate2id function:

```
$('.active').removeClass('active');
$(this).addClass('active');
```

It just removes the class from the link.
But this does not add the class to any of the link. How I can fix that?

**Edit:**
Here is complete jQuery function:

```
function Animate2id(id){ 
    var animSpeed=2000; 
    var $container=$("#container"); 
    if(ease){ 
        var easeType=ease;
    } else {
        var easeType="easeOutQuart"; 
    }

    $container.stop().animate({"left": -($(id).position().left)}, animSpeed, easeType);
}
```

Comment: What is the function wrapper around your JQuery code? It looks like may be and I'm saying may be because I cannot see all your code. But are you sutre in that function $(this) is the object clicked and also why are you using onClick try using $("#ObjectName").click(function() {//Put code here});    Can you please paste your entire JQuery function.

Comment: @PashaImmortals I just added the function, please have a look.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have the `<a>` tags in a parent element with an id, you can do this:

```
$('#parent_element_of_links a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#parent_element_of_links a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/fDZ97/

You could also just put the code above in your `Animate2id()` function that you have:

```
function Animate2id(id, ease) {
    var animSpeed = 2000;
    var $container = $("#container");
    if (ease) {
        var easeType = ease;
    } else {
        var easeType = "easeOutQuart";
    }

    $container.stop().animate({
        "left": -($(id).position().left)
    }, animSpeed, easeType);

    // remove "active" class from all links, add it to this one
    $('#parent_element_of_links a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
}​
```

---

### Update

The `this` keyword wasn't working because it was referring to the window rather than the link. So I added an extra parameter in the function and it works perfectly now, just remember to add `this` in the onclick (right before you define the `ease` variable):

```
function Animate2id(id, t, ease) {
    var animSpeed = 2000;
    var $container = $("#container");
    if (ease) {
        var easeType = ease;
    } else {
        var easeType = "easeOutQuart";
    }

    $container.stop().animate({
        "left": $(id).position().left
    }, animSpeed, easeType);

    // remove "active" class from all links, add it to this one
    $('#links a').removeClass('active');
    $(t).addClass('active');
}​
```

Working jsFiddle Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Uqqmy/

Comment: Thanks, Please see my post above, I added the complete function of Animate2id. I tried to add your code in that function, it just removes the class but does not add.

Comment: Did you change `#parent_element_of_links` to the actual parent element's id? If you add my first code in a `$('document').ready(function() { });` (not inside the `Animate2id()` function) then it should work (as it works in the jsfiddle example).

Comment: Each link is inside `li` which is inside `ul`. I tried `li a` and also `ul li a`

Comment: Yes, your first code works, but I was wondering if there's a way to add inside the Animate2id function.

Comment: @user1117313 I have updated my answer and a new jsfiddle. The problem was that 'this' wasn't referring to the anchor. But it works now as long as you define `t` as `this` in the onclick.

Answer (score 4):

A better way to do this would be to remove the function call from your anchor tags, and instead create a jQuery event handler.

I've got an example here in jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/3AKU3/

Answer (score 3):

This should help

```
$("a").on("click", function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $(this).addClass("active"); 
   $(this).siblings().removeClass("active");
});
```

Comment: How does one add or remove a class and still allow the default behaviour of the clicked link?

Answer (score 3):

Ok thanks for pasting the code, try this:

First wrap the group of anchor tags in a div, so you can seperate them out from the other anchors on your page, and they will be grouped:

So:

```
<div id="anchorGroup">
<a class="active" href="#">Content 1</a>
<a href="#">Content 2</a>
<a href="#">Content 3</a>
</div>
```

Then try this JQuery code:

```
    $("#anchorGroup a").click(function() {
    $("#anchorGroup a").removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');

});
```