# adding active class in django according to anchor in url

Tags: django

I want to create one page site with navbar links which redirect to some part of the page. 
How add class "active" to a link if url is based on anchor (#)?

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li {% if request.path == "/" %} class="active"{% endif %}>
      <a href="{% url "index" %}">Main pge</a>
    </li>
    <li {% if 'about_us' in request.path %} class="active"{% endif %}>
      <a href="#about_us">About us</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contacts">Contacts</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: The anchor is *not* submitted to the server, hence Django can not do that. You will need some JavaScript to do that.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Could you show an example of such JavaScript code or reference to it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery: adding class to link if its clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9659077/jquery-adding-class-to-link-if-its-clicked)

Comment: If you don't have jquery, you can do this in plain javascript as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26959219/javascript-onclick-addclass